# Copy Java List BY VALUE

Tags: java, list, copy

I have seen this answer to this question but it does not copy values.

```
 List<SomeBean> newList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>(otherList);
```

I need to have two separate lists because I want to modify elements in the new list and compare them to the original.If I do it this way, editing objects in newList also modifies them in otherList.

How is this done in java?

Answer (score 2):

### Deep Copy (change item in one, no change in the other)

This code will create a new list, and then create a clone of each object from the old list and add it to the new list.

```
List<SomeBean> newList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>(otherList.size());
for(SomeBean item : otherList) {
    newList.add(item.clone());
}
```

### Shallow Copy (change item in one, changes in the other)

The example you posted *should* work, but there's another way if it doesn't:

```
List<SomeBean> newList = new ArrayList<SomeBean>(otherList.size());
Collections.copy(newList, otherList);
```

This makes a new list the same size as the other one, and then copies the values.

Comment: This throws an error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Source does not fit in dest

Comment: Ok I had the copy params backwards. It does not have an error but when an object member is changed in newList, it changes the same object member in otherList.

Comment: @user2568374 I've updated my answer so that it shouldn't do that: see the __Deep Copy__ heading's code.

Comment: @user2568374 Which code block - the __Deep Copy__ one or the __Shallow Copy__ one? Does it still throw a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I see the first answer change but if there is no clone method that will not be possible.

Comment: By changing this as I was answering this has made this answer very confusing. The second one still throws an error. The first uses clone() but the object has to have that, I am in the process of creating a clone method for it now. In that clone method I and copying each member to the newly created object and then returning that new object. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @user2568374 Yes, that's what `clone()` should do. Sorry if it's been confusing.

Comment: Well I got it to not change when i change the other one but now I am not able to use object.equals(obj). So I guess I have to create my own object.compareTo(obj) method too? And then compare each field of both objects?

Comment: I believe you will have to, yes.